Zabbix Proxy 6.4 Cannot send heartbeat message to 'server'
I have configured a Zabbix Proxy version 6.4 and I am trying to add it to my zabbix server, but I am getting 'last seen age' as never.
The installation process was the following one:
wget https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/6.4/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_6.4-1+ubuntu22.04_all.deb 
dpkg -i zabbix-release_6.4-1+ubuntu22.04_all.deb 
 apt update 
 apt upgrade 
apt install zabbix-sql-scripts 
apt install zabbix-proxy-mysql  
apt-get install mysql-server 
 mysql -uroot -p 
mysql> create database zabbix character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_bin; 
mysql> create user zabbix@localhost identified by ‘updatev6’; 
mysql> grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost; 
mysql> Flush privileges; 
mysql> set global log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1; 
mysql> quit; 
cat /usr/share/zabbix-sql-scripts/mysql/proxy.sql | mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -uzabbix -p zabbix 
Disable log_bin_trust_function_creators 
mysql -uroot -p 
mysql> set global log_bin_trust_function_creators = 0; 
mysql> quit; 

Configuramos /etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.conf 
 
DBPassword=updatev6 
ProxyConfigFrequency=100 
Server=monitoring6.controlsistemes.com  
Hostname=monitoringproxy 
ServerPort=10051 
ListenPort=10056 
StartPollers=100 
StartVMwareCollectors=5 
VMwareCacheSize=512M 
TLSConnect=psk 
TLSAccept=psk 
TLSPSKIdentity=PROXY-”NOMBRE CLIENTE”-01 
TLSPSKFile=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.psk 

 openssl rand -hex 32 | nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.psk   (copiar WPA) 
 chown zabbix:zabbix /etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.psk 
 chmod 644 /etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.psk 

sudo systemctl restart zabbix-proxy 
sudo systemctl enable zabbix-proxy 
 
Apt install zabbix-agent  
sudo systemctl restart zabbix-agent 
sudo systemctl enable zabbix-agent 
Systemctl status zabbix-agent 

Once I finished the process and also added it to the zabbix server, I get the following error on the logs:
enter image description here
Note: the hostname of the proxy registered on the zabbix server, zabbix proxy and zabbix proxy.conf file are the same.
What might be the problem?
